# JCR SQL2 query with a property containing '.' char

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

I'm currently migrating away form Xpath queries to JCR SQL2 ones.

The main problem I'm experiencing is that many of my properties contains the '.' char that is reserved and I couldn't find a proper way to escape it.

JCR offers a simple way to bind values, but I couldn't find any option for doing the same with properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '.' character is not used in JCR names as a metacharacter, and therefore has no need to be escaped. JCR-SQL2 queries should allow such characters to be unescaped, though you can always try to surround the (qualified or expanded) property names with square brackets.

```
SELECT [acme:property.1], [acme:property.2] FROM [acme:myType] ...
```

Comment: I was forgetting the squared brackets. It works now.